# Copying 16-bit data with DMA on the STM32

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, stm32

How do I use DMA to copy ADC data into a 16-bit buffer? The STM32F373 has a 16-bit ADC that can be read using the HAL function:
`HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_SDADC_InjectedStart_DMA(SDADC_HandleTypeDef *hsdadc, uint32_t *pData, uint32_t Length)`

This DMA initializer wants a pointer to an array of `uint32_t` values. However, the ADC's native data format is `int16_t` so I want DMA to put the data into `int16_t adc_data[ADC_BUFFER_LENGTH]` by calling:

`HAL_SDADC_InjectedStart_DMA(&hsdadc, adc_data, ADC_BUFFER_LENGTH);`

This seems to work fine but throws an incompatible pointer type warning. I am confused about the correct way to fix this. Should I passing `(uint32_t*)adc_data` instead? How does the DMA know the correct array step size for a 16-bit array vs a 32-bit array? What would have happened if I passed an `int32_t` array instead, would the data align correctly?

When I dig into `HAL_SDADC_InjectedStart_DMA()` I find the call to: `HAL_DMA_Start_IT(DMA_HandleTypeDef *hdma, uint32_t SrcAddress, uint32_t DstAddress, uint32_t DataLength)` which only takes generic uint32_t pointers without any reference to the step increment. This leaves me more confused about how this actually works.

Note: While I am specifically trying to get this STM32 ADC to work I think this question is much more general. There are many times you might want to copy 16-bit data with DMA.

Comment: I don't know anything about the HAL functions, but normally DMA hardware is configured for data width prior to activation. DMA hardware in some models have some kind of FIFO and allow different data widths for source and destination.

Comment: read Reference manual for the STM32F3 and everything will be clear. HAL is written a very bad way

Comment: The `DMA->CCR` register has bit fields for setting the source data size and destination data size, how you set this via HAL though I don't know.

Comment: I finally found where the DMA is being configured for HALFWORDS in `HAL_SDADC_MspInit()`. The way the HAL is written is very confusing at times. The HAL_SDADC_InjectedStart_DMA() function is misleading with it's pointer to 32-bit data when what is actually needed here is just a memory address. The DMA does take care of the indexing on its own so a certain type should not be implied.